# How can I properly place a UIButton on top of a loaded SFSafariViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I have read many articles about the SFSafariViewController and I believe that it offers splendid functionality in iOS apps. However, when I load my SFSafariViewController, I intentionally hide the navigation bar because I want one custom fixed button in the upper left corner to dismiss the view controller.

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let safariViewController = PSSafariViewController(url: URL(string: blogUrl)!, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
    present(safariViewController, animated: false) {
        var frame = safariViewController.view.frame
        let OffsetY: CGFloat  = 44
        frame.origin = CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y - OffsetY)
        frame.size = CGSize(width: frame.width, height: frame.height + OffsetY)
        safariViewController.view.frame = frame
        let btn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 400, width: 100, height: 50))
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        btn.setTitle("Click Me", for: .normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PSBlogViewController.buttonAction), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        btn.tag = 1 // change tag property
        btn.isOpaque = true
        safariViewController.view.addSubview(btn)
        safariViewController.view.bringSubview(toFront: btn)
        print(btn.description)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I alter the frame so that the bar at the top is not visible. That code runs fine. But when I try to add a UIButton, it appears briefly and then is covered when I run the app. It's a simple blog reader app that uses the SFSafariViewController. Maybe Apple doesn't want developers running around messing with this, but any solutions or workarounds to make the button stay visible are greatly appreciated!

Here's the info about the button: 0x7f950b618db0; frame = (100 400; 100 50); tag = 1; layer = CALayer: 0x60000023ab60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely true that Apple won't want the `SFSafariViewController` to be obscured. However, I did figure out that when I present it, in the completion block I can add a button and what was causing trouble was that I had to increase the `zPosition` of the layer of the button's view like so:

```
    present(safariViewController, animated: false) {
                var frame = safariViewController.view.frame
                let OffsetY: CGFloat  = 44
                frame.origin = CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y - OffsetY)
                frame.size = CGSize(width: frame.width, height: frame.height + OffsetY)
                safariViewController.view.frame = frame
                self.btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50))
                self.btn.layer.cornerRadius = 25
                self.btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 170/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 0.5)
                self.btn.setTitle("←", for: .normal)
                self.btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(safariViewController.buttonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                self.btn.tag = 1 // change tag property
                self.btn.isOpaque = true
                safariViewController.view.addSubview(self.btn)
                safariViewController.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.btn)
                self.btn.layer.zPosition = safariViewController.view.layer.zPosition + 1
                for subview in safariViewController.view.subviews {
                    subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                }
                self.btn.isEnabled = true
                self.btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                //print(self.btn.description)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use one of the other WebView classes to get the extra functionalities you desire?

> 5.1.1 (iv) SafariViewContoller must be used to visibly present information to users; the controller may not be hidden or **obscured by
>   other views or layers**. Additionally, an app may not use
>   SafariViewController to track users without their knowledge and
>   consent.